# Store date as Indian Time in MongoDb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I am trying to store Date in Indian format in MongoDB, However it is storing date in UTC format, Is there anyway to store Date as Indian format in MongoDB from DotNet API?
Or anyother global workaround there?

Comment: Date values in MongoDB are stored as UTC time - **always and only**. If you need to store the input time zone, then you have to store it in a separate field.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/model-time-data/#overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no way to store Date as Indian format in Mongo Db not only Indian format Date, Date Time  can be **only store as UTC Time** in Mongo DB.

I don't want to store date as a different field, so I come up with an work around for that, The thing is we can store Date as in UTC format itself in DB but once we querying we can change that to IST format in API before performing any of our customized operation.

So I tried two set of different methods for convert to IST and Convert to UTC, And I did Benchmark on those methods also, And Adding/subtracting time method seems to be faster and using almost no memory allocated, Here is the code and Benchmark result

```
        public static DateTime ConvertIstToUtc(DateTime date)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
        }
        public static DateTime ConvertUtcToIst(DateTime date)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date,TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
        }

        public static DateTime ConvertIstToUtcByAddSub(DateTime date)
        {
            return date.AddHours(-5).AddMinutes(-30);
        }
        public static DateTime ConvertUtcToIstByAddSub(DateTime date)
        {
            return date.AddHours(5).AddMinutes(30);
        }
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ConvertToIstMethod1 | 181.97 ns | 3.696 ns | 6.176 ns | 0.0381 | 80 B |
| ConvertToUtcMethod1 | NA | NA | NA | - | - |
| ConvertToIstAddSubMethod2 | 39.21 ns | 0.540 ns | 0.479 ns | - | - |
| ConvertToUtcAddSubMethod2 | 52.96 ns | 1.097 ns | 1.708 ns | - | - |